# extjs grid summary row, got concated Strings

Tags: extjs, grid, nan, summary

I am trying to get the summary of a column,
followed an example, summary row is there,
but the cell values are concatenated Strings...

For example, with cell values in a column "6","0","0"
i get "600" in the summary.

In grid declaration i put

```
features: {ftype: 'summary'}
```

and in column declaration:

```
summaryType: 'sum'
```

I know that javascript handles values as a String,
i tried embracing it with parseInt(value)

```
summaryRenderer: function (value, summaryData, dataIndex) {
    return parseInt(value);
}
```

but no effect, what i am doing wrong?

(strangely, In the examples, it works without parseInt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of interest, is the `type` property for the field in question set to `int` on your [model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model)?

Incidentally also see [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?195378-Summary-Feature-with-sum-type-bugs-out-with-strings) on the Sencha forum